# Method To Find The Object That Occurs Most

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I have objects called Pins that users can post to the site. The pins have an artist attribute that belongs to them.

Is there a method that will find which artist name is most posted to the site? Basically I need to find the mode average of Pin.all.

To Expand: This is a music review site. Users post reviews of albums. The posts are called Pins. Each Pin has an :album, :artist, etc.

What I'm looking to do is list stats of the site. I have @pins.count for total pins, and @users.count for total users. I want to list which album got reviewed the most, which artist got reviewed most, etc. something like:

```
<h4>The most reviewed artist on the site: </h4><%= mostReviewed %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up putting the following code in the page controller:

```
@popular_artist = Pin.count(:all,
                            :group => 'artist',
                            :order => 'count(*) DESC').first
```

And the following in my view to display just the artist name:

```
<%= @popular_artist[0] %>
```

Comment: If your own answer was the best one, be sure to give it the the check mark.  This helps others who find your question to quickly see which answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use `each_with_object`...

```
@hash = Pins.scoped.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |pin, hash|
          hash[pin.artist.id] += 1
        end
```

This would return a hash where the keys are the `artists` ID, and the value is the count of how many `Pins` had that artist...

If there are a significant number of `Pins`, you could do it with `find_each`:
      @hash = Hash.new(0)

```
  Pins.find_each do |pin|
    @hash[pin.artist.id] += 1
  end
```

If you put either of the above in a controller method, `@hash` would be available to a helper method, which you could then use to get the most reviewed artist.  For example:

```
def mostReviewed
  @hash.max_by {|key, value| value }.first
end
```

This will give you the key (or artist) with the highest value, which can be used in a view like:

```
<h4>The most reviewed artist on the site: </h4><%= mostReviewed %>
```

Comment: I would post these in the pages controller and call <%= @hash %> ?

Comment: Ideally this would be called in a helper method to make it look good in a view.  But yes, this would / could be called in an action on your controller.

Comment: I'm sorry @CDub I'm not quite getting it to work yet. I can post the first block of code above in the pins_helper.rb file and I would wrap it in a method like def mostPosted. Then in the view I'd call <%= mostPosted %> correct?

Comment: Well, that would return a hash.  You'd want to change either the return result of the helper method or modify the result in the view to get what you want.  Maybe post your desired result in your question and I'll help with the answer.

Comment: Sorry not to be too descriptive. I started the question hoping there would just be a method already to get the "mode". I added more info above.

Comment: ok, when I paste the @hash = Pins.scoped....code in my "about pages controller, I get uninitialized constant PagesController::Pins. I googled the error and everyone keeps mentioning routes, but I don't see why my page routes would change.

Answer (score 0):

```
artists = Hash.new(0)
Pin.all.each { |pin| artists[pin.artist] += 1 }
```

Comment: `all.each` can be pretty inefficient when there is a large number of rows in the Pins table. This may even lead to exceeding the available memory. `find_each` offers a more sensible behavior because it doesn't require the entire table to be kept in memory at once. ([Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html))